# I want to perform numerical integration on a function I define myself

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

```
S[w_, l_, m_, mi_, ma_] := {
 so = NSolve[{r + 2 m*Log[r/(2 m) - 1] == mi}, r];
 bd = r /. so;
 
 sol =
  NDSolve[{\[Phi]''[
       s] + (w^2 - (R[s] - 2*m)/
          R[s]*((l*(l + 1))/R[s]^2 + (2*m)/R[s]^3)) \[Phi][s] == 0, 
    R'[s] == 1 - (2*m)/R[s], \[Phi][mi] == 1, \[Phi]'[mi] == -I*w, 
    R[mi] == bd[[1]]}, {\[Phi], R}, {s, mi, ma}];
 Pfun = \[Phi] /. sol[[1, 1]];
 Rfun = R /. sol[[1, 2]];
 Abs[Exp[-2*I*w*ma]*(I*w*Pfun[ma] + Pfun'[ma])/(
   I*w*Pfun[ma] - Pfun'[ma])]
 }
NIntegrate[S[x, 0, 1, -20, 20], {x, 0, 1}]
```

**I found that the function I defined must require inputting a number first, not x**

**How to perform numerical integration on my S[x,0,1,-20,20]?**

**Perhaps there is a way for mma to execute {x,0,1} first?**

Comment: I was able to get a numerical answer after making two changes to the definition of $S$.  First, use `S[w_?NumericQ,l_,m_,mi_,ma_]` as the lefthand side of the definition of $S$.  Second, replace the curly { } braces on the definition of $S$ with parentheses ( ).